# Hide a property from object inspector in delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to make a new component. 
How can I hide the `Caption` property in the object inspector?
I use `TPanel` as ancestor class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you remove a property from a descendent component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961579/how-do-you-remove-a-property-from-a-descendent-component)

Comment: This question is so common, I'm surprised it didn't get closed a lot quicker...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

by using  [UnlistPublishedProperty](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/DesignIntf.UnlistPublishedProperty). At this link http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/tip-removing-a-property-at-design-time/ you can find a fully explained example.

LE: as good practice you should create another class, descendant of TCustomPanel and publish only the properties you need/want.

Comment: Thanks It was totally useful

Comment: Thanks It was totally useful

Comment: Better not to publish it in the first place. The component's consumer can still modify at run time otherwise.

Comment: Better derive your control from `TCustomPanel` as kobik suggests and publish only properties you want.

Comment: Yes, it is more correct to do it as David and TLama suggested. This is only another way to do things.

Answer (score 14):

Use `TCustomPanel` as the base class and publish the properties you need.