# TPageControl: how to prevent changing Style property

Tags: delphi, vcl

I want to prevent a descendant of `TPageControl` from having a `Style` property except `tsTabs`.

At first glance I tried to override `SetStyle`, but it is declared private in the base class. anyone have ideas?

Comment: Just use some self-restraint.

Comment: I would have expected a `TCustomPageControl` to be available. but there is non. see related Q which might help: [How do you remove a property from a descendent component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961579/how-do-you-remove-a-property-from-a-descendent-component)

Comment: @kobik: `TPageControl` derives from `TCustomTabControl`. But in any case, most of the techniques described in that link simply hide the property at design-time, but the property is still accessible to code at run-time.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I know it derives from `TCustomTabControl`. but deriving from `TCustomTabControl` requires copying most of the code from `TPageControl` which is not practical. I added the link because its *related* (and might even be a duplicate).

Comment: A possible solution might be to introduce a new published `Style` property and handle the getter and setter (if any) accordingly to the inherited `Style`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TPageControl` does not natively support what you are asking for.  To accomplish what you are asking for, you would have to either:

1. have your component re-declare the `Style` property with new getter/setter methods, and then have the setter exit without doing anything.  However, the inherited `Style` property will still technically be accessible at runtime if the user of the component really wants to access it.
2. derive your component from `TCustomTabControl` instead of `TPageControl`, and re-implement everything that `TPageControl` does, but without promoting the protected `Style` property.  However, the inherited `Style` property will still technically be accessible at runtime if the user of the component really wants to access it.
3. have your component override the virtual `CreateParams()` method and force the `TCS_TABS` window style in the `TCreateParams.Style` field.  The `Style` property will still have whatever value the user assigns (which will also affect the behavior of the `TabPosition` property), but at least the underlying window will always behave as if the `tsTabs` style were being used.
4. use a detouring library to hook `TCustomTabControl.SetStyle()` directly at runtime and make it return without doing anything.

Comment: @kobik: Any procedure/function/method can be hooked at runtime, the tricky part is in getting the memory address of it, and there are ways to do that even for private methods.