# Hide properties and events in new component

Tags: delphi, components, lazarus, freepascal

I created in Lazarus a new component based on TPaintBox. Now in Object Inspector I have all Properties and Events which belong to this base component (TPaintBox).

My question is: can I hide chosen Properties and Events for my component?

For example I would like to leave visible only Width and Height properties.

Can you help me?

Comment: Related: [How do you remove a property from a descendent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961579/) and [Hide Properties (UnlistPublishedProperty)](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=30518.0)

Answer (score 11):

Once a property/event has been published, it cannot be un-published.

However, it can be *hidden* from the Object Inspector, at least (it is still accessible to code).

After your design-time code has registered the component with the IDE, it can then:

- in Delphi, call [`UnlistPublishedProperty()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/DesignIntf.UnlistPublishedProperty) from the `DesignIntf` unit.
- in Lazarus, call `RegisterPropertyEditor()` from the `PropEdits` unit to register the `THiddenPropertyEditor` class for the property/event (see [Hide Properties (UnlistPublishedProperty)](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=30518.0) in the Lazarus forum).

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about Lazarus, but in Delphi `TPaintBox` is a lightweight descendant of `TGraphicControl`. The majority of its declaration is just publishing properties. I don't know what your component is doing, but it might be easier to derive it directly from `TGraphicControl` and duplicate the `TPaintBox` code wherever it actually is needed. Then you can publish only the properties you want. Note that you still have those properties declared published in `TControl` and `TComponent`.

Comment: "*Not sure about Lazarus, but in Delphi `TPaintBox` is a lightweight descendant of `TGraphicControl`*" - it is the same in Lazarus, too.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't hide (unpublish) published properties.

In Delphi most objects are based on a parent classes with all the same properties, but mostly hidden.

So while you can't hide exposed properties you can usually achieve what you want by basing your class on the TCustomxxx instead.

Sadly, TPaintbox is an exception. It is descended from TGraphicControl, but that in turn is descended from TControl which already has a number of published properties, including AlignWithMargins, CustomHint and several others, and that in turn is descended from TComponent which has Name and Tag published. To be fair, you need name for sure, and Tag is not a problem I would think.

If you just had to go back to TGraphicControl, that is not too bad. Just one member and a couple of routines to copy. But to go back to TComponent, which is what you would need to do to hide a number of properties is not really viable.

Comment: "*No, you can't hide (unpublish) published properties*" - actually, you can. See my answer

Comment: @Remy Thanks - I didn't know that.

Comment: FWIW, not all the `TControl` properties you mentioned are published by default. `Cursor` is `public`, and you can make it `published` if you wish.

Comment: @JerryDodge Thanks. Corrected.