# Removing properties from Object Inspector

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I bought the TMS Component pack and want to hide some component properties from displaying in the object inspector.

I am using `UnlistPublishedProperty` to hide them.

It works most of the time. But for some reason e.g. `Anchors` or `StyleSettings` are still displayed.

I am calling it like this:

```
  UnlistPublishedProperty(TAdvEdit, 'StyleElements');
```

The weird thing is that it works on 90% of properties and i can't figure out why it will not hide the other properties from the object inspector.

I could edit the source and comment out the line where it gets published from TCustomEdit but i am wondering why the method with `UnlistPublishedProperty` isn't working.

Thanks!

Comment: See also [How do you remove a property from a descendent component](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15961579/757830).

Answer (score 1):

The properties you are trying to remove are inherited from a higher ancestor class. If you wish to use `UnlistPublishedProperty` to remove these particular properties, you'll have to remove them from the ancestor. However, that would apply to *all* controls, not just the one you're working on.

Comment: Not necessarily. You could use an interceptor class instead of directly modifying the ancestor class. This way your modification presented in interceptor class would only affect the units in which your interceptor class is used. In fact this is the perfect scenario for using of interceptor classes.

Comment: @SilverWarior True, I was aiming at the behavior of how `UnlistPublishedProperty` works.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jerry's answer; there is a solution for deleting properties from sub-components. The third part of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10194662/757830) demonstrates how to filter out properties of a sub-component of a custom component by registering a component PropertyEditor and overriding `GetProperties` to filter specific property names.